# Able to install Flask-bcrypt but not able to import flask bcrypt in my project

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

Hi I am have flask bcrypt installed on my mac but i am not able to import the package in my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a virtual environment. If yes did you activate it. If no, you might have installed it in a different python version than you are currently using in your flask project. I would double check that.

Comment: when i do python --version it says Python 2.7.10 and my project requires python 3.6 version of python which i also have. How to check whether the dependency is installed correctly ? Right now i am not using any virtual environment.

Comment: Did you use pip to install your dependency?

Comment: used pipenv install flask-bcrypt

Comment: You will need to configure pycharm to point to your pipenv virtualenv then https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pipenv.html

Comment: i did pipenv shell and then ran this command $ pipenv install flask flask-sqlalchemy psycopg2 flask-migrate flask-script marshmallow flask-bcrypt pyjwt from this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/@olawalealadeusi896/restful-api-with-python-flask-framework-and-postgres-db-part-1-kbrwbygx5#installing-project-dependencies

Comment: Like I said you might need to configure your editor to recognize where your virtualenv is.

Comment: thanks i was able to access packages in my project folder by configuring use Pipenv with PyCharm as you mentioned